# how to transfer a pandas column to lists by row and make a dictionary base on one column by row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below.

```
     id1            ids1                         Name1        Name2      ids2                     ID     col1  Goal     col2    col3       
0   85643        234,34,11223,345,345_2         aasd1        vaasd1    2234,354,223,35,3435     G-0001     1   NaN       3       1      
1   85644        2343,355,121,34                aasd2                                           G-0001     2   56.0000   4       22     
2   8564312      24 , 23 ,244 ,2421 ,567 ,789   aabsd1                                          G-0002     3   NaN       32      33     
3   8564314      87 ,35 ,67_1                   aabsd2       averabsd   387 ,355 ,667_1         G-00002    4   89.0000   43      44
```

I want to create lists base on name1, ids1, and id1 columns and name2, ids2, and id1 columns. In column ids1 and ids2 have some additional space and need to be removed when transferring to the list. For example, the final result looks like this.

```
aasd1 = ['85643','234','34','11223','345','345_2']

vaasd1 = ['85643','2234','354','223','35','3435']

aasd2 = ['85644','2343','355','121','34']

aabsd1= ['8564312','24','23','244','2421','567','789'] 

...........
```

Also, I want to create a dictionary based on the name1 and name2 columns.
just like below

```
dic = {"aasd1":aasd1, "vaasd1":vaasd1, "aasd2":aasd2, "vaasd1":vaasd1, "aabsd1":aabsd1, "aabsd2":aabsd2, "aabsd2":aabsd2}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df['ids1'] = df['ids1'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: [val.strip() for val in x]).tolist()
data = df.set_index('Name1').apply(lambda x: [x['id1']] + x['ids1'], axis=1).to_dict()
```

`OUTPUT:`

```
for key in data.keys():
    print(key, ': ', data[key])

#OUTPUT
aasd1 :  [85643, '234', '34', '11223', '345', '345_2']
aasd2 :  [85644, '2343', '355', '121', '34']
aabsd1 :  [8564312, '24', '23', '244', '2421', '567', '789']
averabsd :  [8564314, '87', '35', '67_1']
```

`For Second Part use:`

```
data = df.assign(d=df['Name1']).set_index('d')['Name1'].to_dict()
```

`OUTPUT:`

```
{'aasd1': 'aasd1', 'aasd2': 'aasd2', 'aabsd1': 'aabsd1', 'averabsd': 'averabsd'}
```